# Leaflet User Triggered Events

Tags: leaflet

Is there any way to determine whether an event was triggered programmatically or by a user?

We want to reload marker listings when the map moves or zooms, but we are initially setting the bounds of the map with `setBounds()` (http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#rectangle-setbounds) which is also triggering the `moveend` (http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-moveend) and `zoomend` (http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-zoomend) events which is causing the markers to reload twice.

Comment: Sorry for the mixup, delete my previous answer and posted a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a (undocumented) property on the event object called `hard` that gets set when the map is moved by `setBounds` and doesn't get set when the user drags the map or uses the cursors:

```
map.on('moveend', function (e) {
    if (e.hard) {
        // moved by bounds
    } else {
       // moved by drag/keyboard
    }
});
```

Testcase here on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/SloKuB?p=preview

As another option you could bind to event after you've set the bounds so it won't fire when you set the bounds and when you do want to set the bounds afterwards you could first unbind using `.off` and rebind again after setting with `.on`. Something like (untested/hacky):

```
function moveEndHandler () {
    ....
}

map.on('moveend', moveEndHandler);

function mySetBounds (bounds) {
    map.off('moveEnd', moveEndHandler);
    map.setBounds(bounds);
    map.on('moveend', moveEndHandler);
}
```

Comment: Yeah!  We say this as well, it looks like it only works for moveend and not zoomend or dragend.  We are incorporating all of them in determining whether or not to reload markers.

Comment: Added another option to my answer kinda hacky but might also do the trick

Comment: Unlike map.setBounds() & map.fitBounds(), map.setView() will not cause the hard property to be set on the event by default.  Use the option {reset: true} to set the hard property.

Comment: Unfortunately in leaflet version 1.6.0 the e object looks totally different, there's not such property (hard). Does anyone know any other way of detecting if the movement is programmatic or made by the user? Thanks x