# Detect user-initiated pan/zoom operations on Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a Leaflet map which is used for location-sharing. When a user shares their location, a marker displaying their location is added to the map for all other users to see. It auto-fits the map to display all the markers whenever one is added, moved or deleted. I've also added a custom control that can toggle the auto-fit behavior on and off. This all works fine, but I would also like to make the map smart enough to automatically turn off the auto-fit behavior if the user pans or zooms the map.

This turns out to be pretty difficult because I can't find a good way to distinguish whether or not a pan/zoom operation is initiated by the user or by an auto-fit. I was initially listening for the panstart and zoomstart events, but these are also triggered by the auto-fit. I figured that I could set a flag to tell it not to turn off auto-fit when the zoom/pan is caused by auto-fitting. I check this flag first before turning off auto-fit in response to panstart and zoomstart, then clear it when panend and zoomend are received.

This appears to work fine until an auto-fit occurs which does not result in a pan or zoom. Let's suppose that we have a large auto-fitted cluster of markers, and one of the ones in the middle is removed. Since the bound box is unchanged, no pan or zoom is triggered, and therefore the flag telling it not to turn off auto-fit never gets cleared. The next time the user pans or zooms the map, it doesn't turn off auto-fit like it should because it thinks it's still in the middle of an auto-fit operation.

**How do I make it so that I can reliably turn off auto-fitting when the user pans or zooms the map directly, but leave it on when it is panned or zoomed by other means?**

Here is the relevant code:

```
var markers = [];        // Map markers are stored in this array.
var autoFit = true;      // Whether auto-fit is turned on
var lockAutoFit = false; // Temporarily lock auto-fit if true
var map;                 // Leaflet map object

function initMap() {
    // Leaflet map initialized here
    map.on('movestart zoomstart', function() {
        if (!lockAutoFit) {
            autoFit = false;
        }
    });
    map.on('moveend zoomend', function() {
        lockAutoFit = false;
    });
}

function toggleAutoFit() {
    autoFit = !autoFit;

    if (autoFit) {
        lockAutoFit = true;
        fitMap();
    }
}

function addOrUpdateMarker(marker, coords) {
    lockAutoFit = true;
    // do the marker update here
    fitMap();
}

function removeMarker(marker) {
    lockAutoFit = true;
    // remove the marker here
    fitMap();
}

// Pans and zooms the map so that all markers fit in the map view.
// Invoked whenever a marker is added, moved or deleted, or when
// the user turns on auto-fit.
function fitMap() {
  if (!autoFit || !markers.length) {
    return;
  }

  map.fitBounds(new L.featureGroup(markers).getBounds());
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I ended up setting a flag around my `fitBounds` and `setView` calls e.g.:

```
isProgramaticZoom = true
map.fitBounds(new L.featureGroup(markers).getBounds());
isProgramaticZoom = false
```

Then the code to turn off auto-fit:

```
map.on('zoomstart', function() {
  if (!isProgramaticZoom) {
    //turn off auto-fit
  }
})

map.on('dragstart', function() {
  //turn off auto-fit
})
```

Unfortunately, still not ideal but should do the trick

Comment: The flag reset needs to be scheduled after the next animation frame which is when the actual bounds change and zoom events are triggered

Answer (score 1):

You could use drag, dragstart, dragend - at least for the map panning. For map zooming there isn't such an equivalent I think.

Comment: Yeah, the drag ones I was aware of, but like you said, there isn't any such thing for zooming, so it unfortunately doesn't really solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: *This apparently has been removed and no longer works*

This is an old question, but as I found it recently, I think it's still relevent enough that a solution is worthwhile giving.

I followed this solution: [Leaflet User Triggered Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614582/leaflet-user-triggered-events)

which is to use:

```
map.on('dragstart', function (e) {
    if (e.hard) {
        // moved by bounds
    } else {
       // moved by drag/keyboard
    }
});
```

The undocumented e.hard part is the solution here; the comments speak for themselves.

Alternativly, you might want to use `moveend` instead of `dragstart`

Comment: This undocumented flag has since been removed completely from leaflet core so no longer works

Comment: @Wayneio This method is not valid anymore

Answer (score -1):

The [Leaflet reference](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-events) states that it has `zoomstart`, `zoomend` and `zoomlevelschange` events.

Comment: Check the source: I am in fact using zoom events in the code. The problem is that those events are triggered both when the user manually zooms and when auto-fitting occurs. I currently do not have a reliable way to determine whether the event was triggered by the user manipulating the controls, or by an auto-fit operation. That is the problem I'm trying to solve.